# Which Gauss-Markov assumptions are violated in this model?

Tags: regression, self-study

Consider this model where $inc_i$ is family income and $vac_i$ is the family spending on vacation.

$vac_i = beta_0 + beta_1*inc_i + e_i$

Which Gauss-Markov assumptions are likely to be violated by this model ?

GM assumptions:

- 1. $E(x_i|u_i) = 0$ : $u_i$ has a conditional mean of 0 for a given $x_i$
- 2. the $x_i$ and $y_i$ are iid
- 3. Large outliers are unlikely
- 4. Errors are homoskedastic (variance is constant)

My opinion:
Assumptions 1 and 4 are likely to be violated.

- 1 because of omitted variable such as the number of kids
- 4 because I doubt that this model is linear hence there would be heteroskedasticity. A family with a high income can spend a little to a lot. A family with a low income is likely to spend a little.

Is this correct ?

Thank you

**EDIT:** The assumptions cited above are the least square assumptions + homoskedasticity assumptions that are directly equivalent to the Gauss Markov assumptions

Comment: Yes this seems right. In general 1 is always violated, even in its relaxed form. 4 is often violated, but can be corrected quite easily by using robust errors.